# C# web service recompile and update

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, soap

I was just handed a C# web service project and first time doing C# and ASP.NET. The web service and .cs, asmx, and asmx.cs files are located in wwwroot dir of the IIS server. I am writing a PHP SOAP client that calls those asmx files via SOAP. I would like to change some of the hard coded settings in those asmx.cs and .cs files. I have tried the aspnet_compiler and Visual Studio would not load the project. Is there any way to update the code/logic in those files without Visual Studio or recompiling. This project was compiled before. When using VS 2010 - it tries to open the project, converts it and nothing happens. If I have to us VS - any clues why it is not loading those files? It opens them if I open the .cs files individually but then I can't rebuild the project.

Any help/hints would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but it turned out be a Windows profile issue. VS could not load those project files due to my profile being full. Hope it helps someone else in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your project file (.csproj) is interrupted. Refer to other correct project file and fix it manually.

ASP.NET website will auto compile cs and run when asmx first requested. Compiled code is put at bin folder, while cs code is put at app_code folder. Make sure asmx code behide puts to cs file in app_code.